# How to create multiple custom ViewModifiers for a specific View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

## My problem:

I am trying to create a custom `View` which has a set of custom `ViewModifier`s specific to this `View`. Some modifiers are simply different variants of styling. Others add some extra logic to the `View`. But I am stuck on how to achieve this correctly. Or if I'm even on the right track to begin with.

## What have I tried?

I have created a simple custom view

```swift
struct MyView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ...
  }
}
```

And for this custom `MyView` I have created a set of `ViewModifier`s which should be stackable. Some modifiers simply change styling. Others add some extra functionality to the `View`.

```swift
struct ModifierOne: ViewModifier {
  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    ...
  }
}

struct ModifierTwo: ViewModifier {
  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    ...
  }
}

struct ModifierThree: ViewModifier {
  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    ...
  }
}
```

I have created a function for each of those modifiers specific to my `MyView` by creating an `extension`:

```swift
extension MyView {
  func one() -> some View {
    modifier(ModifierOne())
  }

  func two() -> some View {
    modifier(ModifierTwo())
  }

  func three() -> some View {
    modifier(ModifierThree())
  }
}
```

## Where I'm stuck:

Actually this part works fine. As long as I only use at most 1 modifier on my `View`.

```swift
MyView()
  .one() // Works
  .two() // Error: Value of type 'some View' has no member 'two'
```

As soon as 1 modifier is applied. The type of the view is no longer of the type `MyView`. But it is changed into a `ModifiedContent` view.

I understand why this happens. I understand that it has to do with the `Body` type in my `ViewModifier`s and the return type of the custom functions in my `extension`. What I don't know is how to properly solve this.

Comment: Can't you add them to an extension for View?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson not really, as some `ViewModifier`s depend on values in `MyView`

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of this, but you can make and return copies of the `View` in a modifier. IE `func mod() { var c = copy; c.prop = value; return c }` and it stays the same type. Let me know if writing out an answer like that would be helpful

Comment: I fear, you cannot do what you want with a ViewModifier. The modifier is applied to `Content` and all we known about Content is, that it is a type alias to an opaque type, which appearantly conforms to View. So, we can modify any view value in function `body(content:)`.  But even if content would actually be your MyView, the function `body(content:)` does not have this type information in its parameter – even you would also return a `MyView` value.

Comment: If true I think you've uncovered a major design flaw in SwiftUI. Have you tried @ViewBuilder like body uses?

Answer (score -1):

The problem arises from the fact that once you call a modifier method, it no longer returns `MyView` but rather `some View`, which means that subsequent calls to your custom modifiers aren't found on the returned type.

A common solution to this problem is to create a new type that holds both your custom view and the stack of modifiers, and then apply the modifiers in order. Here's an example of how you might achieve that:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    var modifiers: [AnyViewModifier] = []

    var body: some View {
        var content: some View = Text("Hello World") // Replace with your content
        for modifier in modifiers {
            content = content.modifier(modifier)
        }
        return content
    }

    func one() -> MyView {
        var copy = self
        copy.modifiers.append(AnyViewModifier(ModifierOne()))
        return copy
    }

    func two() -> MyView {
        var copy = self
        copy.modifiers.append(AnyViewModifier(ModifierTwo()))
        return copy
    }

    func three() -> MyView {
        var copy = self
        copy.modifiers.append(AnyViewModifier(ModifierThree()))
        return copy
    }
}

struct AnyViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    private let _body: (Content) -> AnyView

    init<Modifier: ViewModifier>(_ modifier: Modifier) {
        _body = { content in
            AnyView(content.modifier(modifier))
        }
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        _body(content)
    }
}
```

With this setup, you can now chain your custom modifiers:

```swift
MyView()
    .one()
    .two()
    .three()
```

The custom view `MyView` now has a property `modifiers` that keeps track of the modifiers to be applied, and the custom modifier methods (`one`, `two`, `three`) each return a new `MyView` with the corresponding modifier appended to the `modifiers` array. Then, inside the `body`, it iterates through the modifiers and applies them in order.

This approach keeps the custom view type (`MyView`) consistent through the chain of method calls, allowing you to apply multiple custom modifiers in sequence.

Comment: This is a practice that will break a lot of how SwiftUI is built to work and will likely be quite inefficient at scale. Watch Demystify SwiftUI from WWDC for why, but the TLDR is avoid `AnyView` whenever possible, which breaks identity.